# Al cambiar la configuración de pantallas en Ubuntu 20.04 se invierten los controles

Tags: ubuntu, configuración

He instalado *Ubuntu* en mi PC y después de unos días cambié la configuración de las pantallas. Tengo seleccionado el modo de unir pantallas, pero las tengo al revés, para pasar de una a otra tengo que hacer lo contrario a lo que sería lógico visualmente.

Cuando cambio esta orientación *(seleccionando en configuración la pantalla y arrastrándola al otro lado)* el ratón selecciona lo que hay en la otra pantalla.

**Poniendo un ejemplo:** Yo tengo abierto *Mozilla* en el monitor 1 y para cerrarlo o seleccionar cualquier cosa, tengo que ir al equivalente en el monitor 2, que está con el escritorio abierto solo.

No se si alguien me puede ayudar sin tener que volver a reinstalar *Ubuntu*, he estado buscando por internet y no encontré a nadie con este problema.

Comment: están mal identificadas. Hay una opción en display que permite ordenarlas. Tienes ubuntu 20.04 con qué manejador de ventanas? Mejor dicho, es ubuntu, kubuntu, xubuntu...?

Comment: al hacer lsb_release -a en el terminal me sale: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende y tu comentario tampoco. Muy a mi pesar, creo que necesitas ampliar la explicación con alguna captura.

Comment: El problema está en que no puedo sacar capturas cuando estoy asi tampoco, no me deja hacer nada. A ver si explicandolo de otra manera consigo que lo entiendas, se que es díficil de entender si no lo tienes delante pero aun asi muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda. Imaginate que tienes dos cajas (mis monitores) y dentro de una caja hay una manzana (en mi pc por ejemplo una ventana de terminal) y en la otra no, bien ahora cambiar la configuracion de las cajas,  la de la derecha que tenia la manzana pasa al lado izquierdo y en la derecha queda la vacia.

Comment: Ahora para coger la manzana tienes que meter la mano en la caja de la derecha y asi cojes la manzana en la que sigue estando en la caja izquierda. Es muy raro pero asi es, cuando le doy a aplicar la configuración , sale la ventana de confirmar y para seleccionar por ejemplo confirmar tengo que darle click en la otra pantalla en la zona donde estaria confirmar si esa ventana estuviera en la otra pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Para la mayoría de los manejadores de ventanas, es posible entrar a la opción Pantallas / Display o similar y ordenar la forma en la que están dispuestos.

Esto es, llegar a esta pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y seleccionar la pantalla que está fuera de sitio (digamos, la roja), sostener el clic y arrastrarla para ubicarla del lado correcto de la verde. Tan sencillo como sostener y arrastrar y ya quedarán las pantallas como las necesitas.

Comment: en el manejador de ventadas las tengo detectadas pero colacadas al reves de como las tengo fisicamente. Pero cuando las coloco tal cual fisicamente están es cuando hay problemas. Para seleccionar x cosa del monitor 1 tengo que mas o menos buscar su localizacion en el monitor 2 ( que no tiene dicha pestaña abierta si no la tiene el 1) y seleccionarla

Answer (score 0):

Me pasa exactamente lo mismo. La pantalla 2(originalmente en la derecha) aparece en el manipulador en la izquierda, y la pantalla 1(originalmente en la izquierda) aparece en el manipulador a la derecha. (Están intercambiadas). Además, estando así, el "centro" de las pantallas está en los extremos de cada pantalla, no en el centro real. Cuando cambio el orden de pantallas. Las ventanas abiertas me aparece en la pantalla de la izquierda(pantalla 2) pero el ratón reacciona al contenido de las ventanas en la pantalla de la derecha(pantalla 1).

Ubuntu 20.4. Configurador de serie de Ubuntu

Comment: La sección de respuestas es únicamente para intentos de resolver la pregunta y no para decir "me sucede lo mismo" puedes formular una pregunta en su lugar, además lee la otra respuestas (tal vez sea de utilidad), por favor borra esto para evitar votos en negativo

Comment: A mi se me solucionó como por arte de magia, o yo diría mas bien sin querer. Me fallaba el virtualbox asi que tuve que reinstalar el dkms y los linux-headers. Cuando probé despues de hacer esa instalación, probé a ver si con el tiempo ya me funcionaría y efectivamente ya no había tal problema. No te puedo decir que haciendo eso el problema se solucione pero yo fue el unico cambio del que me acuerde entre la ultima vez que lo probé sin que funcionase y cuando lo cambié exitosamente